# How can I publish a console app as a build step?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

I have a .NET Core application. I need to build this into a single executable file. The .NET Core Publish seems to work for this and the self-contained deployment is ideal for me. However I've run into a slight hiccup in that I need to reference this as the *build* output, not any separate or additional step. This is due to me needing to reference the desired output for other projects, most notably a WiX installer.

Allegedly MSBuild can be used to publish, so I was thinking of trying to publish as part of the build step. However, I could not find any way to do so that does not involve a bunch of Web stuff, when really I just have a console app I need to make into an executable and do not want or need any Web anything anywhere near.

Is there any way to convert my app into the self-contained deployment as part of the build step?

Comment: Did you ever work out how to do this?